# run cronjob and supervisor in dockerfile

Tags: docker

I am new to docker and trying to run supervisor and corn , but in this file it is just running
supervisor.
I know the problem is with last line but how can I fix it?

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm

# Copy composer.lock and composer.json
COPY composer.lock composer.json /var/www/

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libonig-dev\
    build-essential \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    locales \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl \
    libzip-dev

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y cron

COPY /docker/crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab
#
# Give execution rights on the cron job
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/crontab
RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/crontab

# Create the log file to be able to run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log


RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
COPY docker/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf


CMD /usr/bin/supervisord ; cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

Comment: It's usually better practice to run multiple containers than to run supervisord or a similar multi-process manager.  You can override the `CMD` when you run the container, so you might remove supervisord and the final `CMD` line entirely: if you `docker run` the image you'll get the default `php-fpm` from the base image, and you can also `docker run my-image crond -f` to get a second container running the cron daemon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using ";" after the `supervisord` command, the command waits for `supervisord` to finish and after that `cron` will run. You can make it like:

```
CMD /usr/bin/supervisord & cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log
```

so the `supervisord` will run in the back ground.
If you want the container to fail if `supervisord` fails, you can do it like:

```
CMD cron && tail -f /var/log/cron.log  & /usr/bin/supervisord
```